# Is it possible to reach the huge outcropping overlooking most of central Primordia on foot?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-x

I've just been exploring instead of doing Chapter 4 (so I won't have a Skell for a while). I was hoping to get all of the FrontierNav locations (in Primordia at least) but it appears that the center one is on top of that outcropping. I believe I have made it to the Fifth? Terrace (might just be the third, it was definitely two above the area with the large turkey like indigens.) But I did not see a way up further that I could reach. Is it possible to actually get all the way up just on foot or is a Skell required and that Nav spot has to wait?

A map would also be nice if it is.

Comment: In addition to this, some frontiernav locations require mechanical level 5, which is definitely not obtainable anywhere around chapter 4.

Comment: There are 3 FN Sites in Primordia where you'll need flight, unlocked after Chapter 9: FN Site 110 (the one in the center), FN Site 109 (directly north of it), and FN Site 101 (which requires Mechanical Skill level 5, which in turn requires flight).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not.

You'll visit this area later through a different means as part of an affinity mission available after chapter 9. Very mild spoilers:

> The skell flight affinity mission "A Girls' wings" has you fly to this area and set up the probe. According to the affinity mission, it's impossible to reach this area otherwise.

Completion of that affinity mission is also required in order to obtain the Mechanical level 5 field skill. The quest to obtain Mechanical level 5 can appear after obtaining Mechanical level 4, but you will not have the skills required to complete it until you finish the affinity mission I previously mentioned.

Comment: Actually, the mission can appear at any time after you've reached Mechanical level 4. I haven't started Chapter 7 yet, but I already have the mission in my log.

Comment: Ah, my mistake then. Thanks for pointing that out.